# FreeCAD select all objects without Gui

Tags: python, freecad, stp

I am trying to select all the objects in a stp file using FreeCAD with external python script.
Is there any way to select all the objects form stp file with freecad external script without opening gui

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all Objects like this:

```
for obj in FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.Objects
```

Then you can do something with it...